# Dynamically added elements doesn't trigger events in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `table` which I dynamically add `tr` elements to it. I have a datepicker plugin which is assigned to `inputs` with .from_time and .til_time classes in the `table`. when I dynamically add tr elements which have the same inputs, the event only work in the first tr and not the other `tr`s.

CODE:

**HTML** :

```
<table>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>ردیف</th>
                                    <th>نام شرکت یا سازمان</th>
                                    <th colspan="2">مدت خدمت</th>
                                    <th>آخرین سمت</th>
                                    <th>تعداد پرسنل تحت امر</th>
                                    <th>آخرین حقوق دریافتی</th>
                                    <th>علت ترک خدمت</th>
                                    <th>آدرس و تلفن محل خدمت</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 20px">
                                        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/icons/plus.png" class="plus">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="index">
                                        1
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" id="company_name"  name="company_name" style="width: 100%" >
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="از تاریخ"    class="from_time" name="from_time" style="width: 100%">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="تا تاریخ" class="til_time" name="til_time" style="width: 100%" >
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text"  id="hire_level" size="40" name="hire_level" style="width: 100%">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text"  id="personnel"  size="40" name="personnel" style="width: 100%">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="salary"  style="width: 100%">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" id="out_reason" name="out_reason" style="width: 100%">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <textarea  id="address" rows="2" cols="15" name="address"></textarea>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
$("#military_date, .from_time, .til_time, #job_date").pDatepicker();//function to be triggered for elements
```

I don't know if its an event, I want to run this `.pDatePicker()` on every input dynamically added with classes `.til_time` and `.from_time`

Comment: Can you post your jQuery/JavaScript code ?

Comment: the date picker is bound to all matching objects in the dom at the time, it isn't bound to new ones you add dynamically.

Comment: can you add a demo eith whatever you have done ?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Dynamically added elements will need to get the `.pDatepicker()` run on them.

Longer answer: When you first run your `$("#military_date, .from_time, .til_time, #job_date").pDatepicker();`, it will assign a datepicker to all the matching elements in the *current* DOM. However, when you dynamically update the DOM (ie, by adding elements), they won't have had `.pDatepicker()` run on them.

If you're keeping your new element in a variable, you could just run `new_element.pDatepicker()`, but it's also possible to "take the lazy road" and re-run the `$(".from_time, .til_time").pDatepicker();` instead.

Comment: how to do that @ninetwozero?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.delegate` or `.on` for dynamically generated elements

like bellow

```
$(document).on(event,selector,function(){});
```

Comment: that .pDatePicker() is a function of a plugin, are you sure you can use that with .on() function?

Comment: @1linecode Have a look at this learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: I don't know if its an event, I want to run this .pDatePicker() on every input dynamically added with classes

Comment: event delegation has nothing to do with initializing a plugin

Comment: @RobSchmuecker/others can someone tell what is the reason of downvoting, So I can know the problem.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker sorry for trouble, I thought if there is a problem you could also tell that. thanx

Comment: this is the correct answer. all the OP needs to do is look in the plugin and see how they initialize the plugin, then he can manually initialize it from within the callback of the event.

Comment: No, this is the correct answer, as @r3wt said.  Or perhaps the OP just needs to call the initialisation of the plugin on successfully insertion of rows into the DOM after ajax return again.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker you hit it square on the head, and even simpler. I do recall something about detaching events for properness, but that can be another lesson.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger event on dynamically added element. then you need to bind event to that
element or re-initialize the same function.

```
//Code to add new element here 
// { ------
//------ }

//reinitialize datepicker code
$("#military_date, .from_time, .til_time, #job_date").pDatepicker();
```

Dont forget to accpet answer if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

This is a common situation with jQuery and events, I think you are using .bind() on the elements created on the fly instead of using .on() or .delegate for this purpose.

Comment: `.live()` has been depreciated sense 1.7

Comment: just one note `.live` has been removed from current version of jQuery.

Comment: using event delegation doesn't work for initializing a plugin

Comment: it depends on the jQuery version he is using, why the down vote ? .on() seems to resolve the problem, non ?!